# extract specific words from text

Tags: python

I have the text below:

I have this text < class 'str'>
"pois":[{"addr":"重庆市江北区长兴路2号","cp":" ","direction":"附近","distance":"42","name":"金融街新融御","poiType":"房地产","point":{"x":106.56036820713899,"y":29.577630842401097},"tag":"房地产;住宅区","tel":"","uid":"71785bc6fdf697313fe2315e","zip":"","parent_poi":{"name":"","tag":"","addr":"","point":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0},"direction":"","distance":"","uid":""}},{"addr":"重庆市江北区长兴路2号","cp":" ","direction":"东北","distance":"123","name":"乐融幼儿园","poiType":"教育培训","point":{"x":106.55956871523539,"y":29.57748164058615},"tag":"教育培训;幼儿园","tel":"","uid":"ae5c28352429035ed3ff2381","zip":"","parent_poi":{"name":"","tag":"","addr":"","point":{"x":0.0,"y":0.0},"direction":"","distance":"","uid":""}},{"addr":"重庆市江北区长兴路2号","cp":" ","direction":"东","distance":"58","name":"龙湖春森彼岸2-5栋","poiType":"房地产","point":{"x":106.56003583410042,"y":29.577929245362655},"tag":"房地产;内部楼栋","tel":"","uid":"2982a6e5b02290c58f1a89cb","zip":"","parent_poi":{"name":"龙湖·春森彼岸","tag":"房地产;住宅区","addr":"重庆市江北区北滨一路258号","point":{"x":106.55829312141164,"y":29.576979064412556},"direction":"东北","distance":"279","uid":"9de85c83b09b837888f15d98"}},{"addr":"重庆市江北区长新路与刘家台正街交叉路口往西北约160米","cp":" ","direction":"东","distance":"108","name":"龙湖·春森彼岸-8号车库","poiType":"交通设施","point":{"x":106.55962261356597,"y":29.578141267978038},"tag":"交通设施;停车场","tel":"","uid":"63b440710aa3128fadee7a4a","zip":"","parent_poi":{"name":"龙湖·春森彼岸","tag":"房地产;住宅区","addr":"重庆市江北区北滨一路258号","point":{"x":106.55829312141164,"y":29.576979064412556},"direction":"东北","distance":"279","uid":"9de85c83b09b837888f15d98"}},{"addr":"重庆市江北区长兴路2号","cp":" ","direction":"东","distance":"113","name":"龙湖·春森彼岸-北门","poiType":"出入口","point":{"x":106.55957769829048,"y":29.578149120658855},"tag":"出入口;门","tel":"","uid":"4eabe73ddd66fc9a3a13fd89","zip":"","parent_poi":{"name":"龙湖·春森彼岸","tag":"房地产;住宅区","addr":"重庆市江北区北滨一路258号","point":{"x":106.55829312141164,"y":29.576979064412556},"direction":"东北","distance":"279","uid":"9de85c83b09b837888f15d98"}},{"addr":"北滨路陈家馆A宗E宗","cp":" ","direction":"东","distance":"154","name":"龙湖春森彼岸2-8栋","poiType":"房地产","point":{"x":106.55917346081113,"y":29.577944950757006},"tag":"房地产;内部楼栋","tel":"","uid":"1e3f326e817ccb9fc909f036","zip":"","parent_poi":{"name":"龙湖·春森彼岸","tag":"房地产;住宅区","addr":"重庆市江北区北滨一路258号","point":{"x":106.55829312141164,"y":29.576979064412556},"direction":"东北","distance":"279","uid":"9de85c83b09b837888f15d98"}},{"addr":"重庆市江北区长新路与刘家台正街交叉路口往西约120米","cp":" ","direction":"东北","distance":"197","name":"龙湖星悦荟8区(龙湖星悦荟店)-停车库","poiType":"交通设施","point":{"x":106.55942498635383,"y":29.57672777537788},"tag":"交通设施;停车场","tel":"","uid":"868395aeca61ca754251c078","zip":"","parent_poi":{"name":"龙湖星悦荟8区(龙湖星悦荟店)","tag":"购物;购物中心".....

I want to extract :

- "tag":"房地产;住宅"
- "tag":"教育培训;幼儿园"
- "tag":"房地产;内部楼栋"
- "tag":"交通设施;停车场"
- "tag":"购物;购物中心"

I have tried :
startString = '"tag":'
endString = ',"tel"'''
mySubString.append(result[result.find(startString)+len(startString):result.find(endString)])

but couldn't iterate over the whole text.

Comment: Looks like json, if so you can convert it to dict and extract the tag.

Comment: You should provide minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
import json

data = json.loads(data)
print([el['tag'] for el in data["pois"]])
```

Which will print all the tag in the json.

```
# Output
['房地产;住宅区', '教育培训;幼儿园', '房地产;内部楼栋', '交通设施;停车场', '出入口;门', '房地产;内部楼栋', '交通设施;停车场']
```

Comment: I got this error : TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: I've corrected the code, can you provide more information? since it works perfectly fine with what you provided.

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this works for your solution. I used regex to extract these tags

```
import re

extract_str = [
    '"tag":"房地产;住宅"', '"tag":"教育培训;幼儿园"', '"tag":"房地产;内部楼栋"',
    '"tag":"交通设施;停车场"', '"tag":"购物;购物中心"'
]
with open('./extract_specific_from_text.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    file_txt = f.read()
    for i in extract_str:
        tags = re.findall(i, file_txt)
        if len(tags) > 0:
            print(f'{list(set(tags))[0]} found in the file')
        else:
            print(f'{i} not found in the file')
```